# How could an iOS app store data even if it was deleted?

Tags: ios

For instance the Wordfeud app saves account information even if the app was deleted. I thought this was impossible on iOS? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Likely an external server the app communicates with

Comment: Deleting an app doesn't delete its keychain records.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884847/when-are-ios-keychain-items-removed