# Where to store a JWT token?

Tags: android, security, jwt

I'm implementing a REST service that requires authentication. I am using [JWT](http://jwt.io/).

Now the Android App sends a request when logging in, gets a token, and has to send the token in the header for every subsequent request.

My question is, how to store the token, or where should I store it?

- Shared Preferences
- SQLite Database
- In a file

What would be the *best practice* way to do it? Or am I going about this the totally wrong way?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Nope. I just stored it in the Shared Preferences.

Comment: there's a great discussion about this in reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/470h8a/what_is_the_best_way_to_store_an_auth_token_on/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are using REST service and want to store JWT the best way available is `SharedPreferences`.You should store in `PrivateMode` for security.
`SharedPreference` and `SharedPreference.Editor` is used to store and retrieve JWT. JWT is retrieved after POST request of Username and Password

```
 private void makeJsonRequest() {    
        String json_req = "json_req";
       // String url = getContext().getString(R.string.LOGIN_URL);
            String url="";    
            final JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
            try{
                obj.put("username",name);
                obj.put("password",pass);

            }catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, obj,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {                          
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                
                    }

                }) {          
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                return headers;
            }
        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, json_req);
```

To retrieve JWT from response and save in shared preference use

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
 prefs=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        edit=prefs.edit();
 try {
                         String saveToken=response.getString("token");
                            edit.putString("token",saveToken);
                            Log.i("Login",saveToken);
                              edit.commit();
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

To get Token from SharedPreference

```
private void getToken() {
        prefs=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String token = prefs.getString("token","");
    }
```

Comment: Not only did this answer the same question for me, I wish I would have found it the other day when I was figuring out how to send JSON POST request to REST API.  Good stuff.

Answer (score 23):

I found this ans here ([src](https://stormpath.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-mobile-api-security))

If you’re writing an Android app, for instance, you’ll want to store all access tokens in `SharedPreferences` (here’s the API docs you need to make it work). If you’re an iOS developer, you will want to store your access tokens in the `Keychain`.

[for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793128/access-tokens-persistence-best-practices-ios)

[for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161266/how-to-securely-store-access-token-and-secret-in-android)

Comment: what about rooted devices? Android in particular? is it still safe?