# How to clean keychain when my application is uninstalled on ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, keychain

My application use the keychain to store users and passwords. When I remove and reinstall my app, the keychain is not clean, keys are always in the application.

How to detect the removing of my app and use my cleanKeyChain method ?

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671499/iphone-keychain-items-persist-after-application-uninstall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no observer to get notified if the app gets deinstalled. If the app is not running at that time its useless anyway. You can use bundle props (fresh = true on 1st run) and remove / add things again with a reinstall.