# In iOS 10 KeyChain items are not deleted together with the app

Tags: ios, iphone, security, keychain

In iOS 10 I noticed that KeyChain items are not removed/deleted together when an app gets deleted.

In iOS 8 & 9 KeyChain items were removed together with the app. Does someone noticed this behavior? Is here a way to specify that my KeyChain items should be deleted together with an app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671499/iphone-keychain-items-persist-after-application-uninstall?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: NSUserDefault items are removed together with the app, keychain are NOT